# Import C++ DLL in C# of Entry Point not resolved

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I'm having a problem with dll imports in C#, first i create the dll in C++ resulting in a string and the method which receive a bitmap like this:

```
public ref classMyIdentifier
{
    public:
    string BuscaPlaca(Bitmap);
};
```

If I referenced this dll in C# it returns me a string pointer and needs other string pointer, and a GdiPlus::Bitmap pointer like this:

```
std.basic_string_char,std::char_traits_char_,std::allocator_char__*UR.BuscaPlaca(std.basic_string_char,std::char_traits_char_std::allocator_char__* value, Gdiplus.Bitmap* A_0);
```

And if I use DLLImport like this:

```
[DllImport(@"MyIdentifier.dll", EntryPoint="BuscaPlaca")]
    private static extern string BuscaPlaca(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]Bitmap bmp
    );
```

It returns: it not exists the Entry Point BuscaPlaca

Does someone have a answer by my dilemma, I'm in this crossroads have two days.

Comment: You can't return a `std::string` to a .NET application. It won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Why don't you use String^ as return value? From the declaration of the classMyIdentifier, I hope your project is CLR Class Library. Output of your project will be a managed dll which you can directly refer in your c# project. DllImport/P-Invoke may not be required in your case.

Comment: `String^` in C++/CLI is equivalent to `string` in C#. I assume that you have bunch of things developed in C++ and you have something developed in C#. `[DllImport]` is actually used to import explorted APIs from native DLLs. But if your project is CLR Library (C++/CLI), you should not use DllImport, rather you can directly add the output dll from the CLR project to your C# project and use the class `classMyIdentifier` as you would use any other managed .net class

Comment: Oks, String^ works perfect, i need now translate c# Bitmap into a Gdiplus::bitmap, i see it in other place and will test, if that works i come back. Thank you friend"

Comment: the new Signature is String^ BuscaPlaca(Bitmap);this works fine to Strings and not needs more that string pointers in the referenced dll, but the bitmap pointer still continues and the Signature in c# are this string BuscaPlaca(Gdiplus::Bitmap) and VS give me that method is not supported because the pointer

Comment: You should be using `String^ BuscaPlaca(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmp)` to be able to use it from C#

Comment: Yeah, i see it, thanks a lot friend.

Comment: Oks, my problem now is transform a array<System::Byte>^ myarray into a Gdi+::Bitmap, in the library i have a tlb and that accepts only a Gdi+::Bitmap, not a System::Drawing::Bitmap, i don't find a manner to translate a Gdi to a System::Drawing, then i will receive a array<System::Byte>^ to transform in a Gdi+::Bitmap, the problem is how i will transform it??